# Data extraction using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, extract, data-extraction, pdf-extraction

I want to parse the pdf and extract the data like name address contact details using c#

Pdf data parsing is done using pdfpig
Can anyone suggest or help with data extraction ?
How to extract the exact key value pair from available data.?
Thanks in advance!!

```
BajajAllianzGeneralInsuranceCompanyLtd.RegisteredandHeadOffice:GEPlaza,AirportRoad,Yerwada,PuneTranscriptofProposalforPrivateCar-PackagePolicyDearRAJINDERKUMARGUPTA,Wewishtoinformyouthatthecontractunderpolicynumber'OG-17-1104-1801-00011267'hasbeenfinalizedbasedontheinformationanddeclarationgivenbyyou,thetranscriptwhereofismentionedbelow.Youarerequestedtoreconfirmthesame.Incaseofanydisagreementorobjectionoranychangeswithrespecttoinformationmentionedbelow,werequestyoutopleaserevertbackwithinaperiodof15daysfromdateofyourreceiptofthis,failingwhichitwillbedeemedthatyouaresatisfiedwiththecorrectnessofthedetailsmentionedbelow.Kindlynotethatasthecontentsanddeclarationscontainedinthistranscriptisthebasisonwhichwehaveissuedthepolicytoyou,weadviseyoutopleaseensurethatyouhaveprovided/disclosedandornotwithheldanymaterialfacts/informationanddeclarations,asPolicybecomesVoidabinitioifmaterialfactsarenotprovided/disclosedandorwithheldandinsuchcasenoclaim,ifany,willbeconsideredbyusapartfromforfeitureofthepremium.Detailsprovidedbyyou:A.Proposerdetails1.ProposerName:RAJINDERKUMARGUPTA2.ProposerAddress:NEARPIPALCHOWK,ASSANDH,,KARNAL,HARYANA-1320393.ProposerMobileNumber:4.ProposerResidentialNumber:NA5.Proposere-mailid:NA6.ProposerProfession:NAB.VehicleDetailsRegistrationNumberMonth/YearofRegnVehicleMakeVehicleModelVehicleSubTypeCubicCapa-cityFuelTypeYearofMan-ufactureSeatingCa-pacityHR40A4511OCT/2004MARUTIALTOSTANDARD796Petrol20045EngineNumberChassisNumberVehicleIDV(inRs.)ElectricalAccessoriesIDV(inRs.)Non-ElectricalAccessoriesIDV(inRs.)CNG/LPGUnit(Extrafitted)IDV(inRs.)TotalIDV(inRs.)0109910973478100000081000C.Coverageopted1.PeriodofInsurance:From20-OCT-201600:01(Hrs)To19-OCT-2017Midnight2.IsyourvehiclefittedwithexternalLPG/CNGkit:No.3.ElectricalAccessoriescoverOpted(IfApplicable):No.4.Non-ElectricalAccessoriescoverOpted(IfApplicable)::No.5.IsVoluntaryExcessopted:No.Amountofvoluntaryexcessopted:Rs.NA.6.WhetherPAcoverisoptedforowner-driver:Yes.7.Isanyadditionalcompulsorydeductibleimposedandagreedupon:No.Amountofadditionalcompulsorydeductibleimposed:NA.8.Whethergeographicalareaextensionisopted:No.DetailsofCountriestowhichgeographicalareaextensioncoverisgiven:NA.9.IsLLtopersonforPaiddriver/Operation/Maintenanceopted:Yes.10.WhetherPAcoverisoptedforpaiddriverotherthanownerdriver:No.SumInsuredforPaidDriver:Rs.NA.11.WhetherPAcoverisoptedforpassengers:No.SumInsuredperPassenger:Rs.NA.12.IsTPPDrestrictedtostatutorylimitofRs.6000?:No.13.PreExistingdamagesinthevehicle:CostofRepair/ReplacementtowardsthedamagedpartsnoticedduringtheinspectionofyourvehiclepriortoenrolmentunderthispolicyasperInspectionreportreferencenumber2016-02305432dulysignedbyyouoryourrepresentativeaswellasthephotographsshallbeexcludedintheeventofanyfutureclaims.14.PremiumforLiabilitycoverage,quotedandagreeduponis:Rs.2205.15.PremiumforODcoverage,quotedandagreeduponis:Rs.861.16.TotalPremium(excludingServiceTaxandEducationCess)forLiabilityandODcoverages,quotedandagreeduponis:Rs.306617.NCB(NoClaimBonus)claimedbyyouandgrantedbyusbasedonyourdeclarationofnoclaimduringyourpreviouspreviouspolicy:-50%.18.Aboutthelastinsurancecompany(i)InsuranceProvider:IFFCOTokioGeneralInsuranceCompanyLimited..(ii)PreviousPolicyNo:1-3S5LBHC,PreviousPolicyExpiryDate:01-SEP-1619.WhetheryourvehicleisHypothecatedandifsothedetailsofPledgeewhosenameisregisteredbyus:No.NameofPledgee:NA.20.AddonCover(s)opted:No.Planname:NAPleasenoteCoverNoteNo.DY1303078914/19-OCT-201610:20issuedtoyoubasingontheaboveinformation.IncaseofDisagreementorobjectionoranychangeswithrespecttoinformationandcontentsmentionedhereinabove,pleasecontactourtollfreenumber&registeryourobjections/changes/disagreementtothecontentsofthistranscriptoryoumayalsosendusemailorwrittencorrespondenceatthefollowingdetailswithinaperiodof15daysfromdateofyourreceiptofthistranscriptalongwithPolicy:I/WeherebyunconditionallyallowtheCompanytoshareallmy/ourinformationbeingcollectedinthisproposalformorthroughtelephonic/email/web-inputsmeansorothermeans,asupdatedfromtimetotimewithingroupentities.TollfreeNumber:1800-22-5858,1800-102-5858,1800-209-5858Emailaddress:customercare@bajajallianz.co.inWebsite:www.bajajallianz.comContactourpolicyservicingbranchat:BlockNo-4,7thFloor,DLFTowers,,15,ShivajiMarg,,-,NewDelhi-110015PH:011-66278000.♦♣♠
```

I want to extract the ProposerName

Comment: let me understand, you could successfully convert the pdf to text and now you want to extract the data? well, it depends in how your final text file looks like. you may use regex patterns or if it has a .csv format or something you can just split the text into lines (by the '\n'), and then split each line by the columns. it depends.

Comment: if you haven't done it yet, you can use pdftotext to transform it into text
https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html
and then you extract the data.

Comment: I have updated the question description. Is it a way to choose ProposerName with its value.

Comment: And I have answered it yesterday :D Just fixed a little detail in the `regexPattern` string. Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this piece of the string:
`Proposerdetails1.ProposerName:RAJINDERKUMARGUPTA2.ProposerAddress:NEARPIPALCHOWK`

Do you see the pattern `<Key>:<Value>.` like in `ProposerName:RAJINDERKUMARGUPTA2.`?

What you want is to find this particular Key/Value pair from the text and take the value.

You may use [Regular Expressions (Regex)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-regex-examples/).

```
//Imagine that your data is stored here in 'fullText'
public static string GetProposerName(string fullText)
{

   /* Here's the regex filter for us to find a piece of string in the data with the 
    * key ProposerName, some value that we don't know yet and a . termnation.
    * Now take a look in the content inside the (). 
    * This is a group. The symbols between it means that we
    * want to get everything, any content, that is there inside the group. */
   string regexPattern = "ProposerName:(.*?)\\.";

   //Use this classes from System.Text.RegularExpressions
   Match match = Regex.Match(fullText, regexPattern);

   //Important test, it may not find anything...
   if (!match.Success) return null;

   /* If your code reaches here means that you've find the pattern inside the text.
    * Now you take only the value inside the group as a string and voila!*/
   string proposerName = match.Groups[0].Value;

   return proposerName;
}
```